# Determine which vectors in $R^5$ belong to the span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Determine which vectors in $R^5$ belong to both $span$ {$(a_{1}, b_{1}, c_{1}, d_{1}, e_{1}), (a_{2}, b_{2}, c_{2}, d_{2}, e_{2})$} and $span$ {$(f_{1}, g_{1}, h_{1}, i_{1}, j_{1}), (f_{2}, h_{2}, i_{2}, j_{2}, k_{2}), (f_{3}, g_{3}, h_{3},
>  i_{3}, j_{3})$}.
>
> where $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f,h,i,j,k$ are random vector components that I put as an example.

**Question:** How do i actually find the vector in $R^5$ in both the spans? It would be great if someone could explain the concept behind this because I do not actually get what the question is asking for.

**My Attempt:**

My only guess of doing this is the following (thus i need guidance): 
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a_{1} & b_{1} & c_{1} & d_{1} & e_{1} \\
        a_{2} & b_{2} & c_{2} & d_{2} & e_{2}\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        f_{1} & g_{1} & h_{1} & i_{1} & j_{1}\\
        f_{2} & g_{2} & h_{2} & i_{2} & j_{2}\\
        f_{3} & g_{3} & h_{3} & i_{3} & j_{3}\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

and reduce them in their row-echelon forms, even then I do not know how to proceed because I really do not understand the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can see how things like this work in a practile example. For simplicity, I will consider $\mathbb{R}^3$ being the vector space and I'll give the values of the vectors in the span, and the other cases will be quite similar.

"Determine which vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ belong to both $span\{(0,1,1),(1,-1,1)\}$ and $span\{(0,1,2),(1,0,1)\}$."

This is, find $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $v \in span\{(0,1,1),(1,-1,1)\} \cap span\{(0,1,2),(1,0,1)\}$ $\Rightarrow$ Exists elements $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ on the field such that $v = a_1(0,1,1)+a_2(1,-1,1) = a_3(0,1,2)+a_4(1,0,1)$ (each equality is because v is in each span)  $\Rightarrow$ $(a_2,a_1-a_2,a_1+a_2) = (a_4,a_3,2a_3+a_4) \Rightarrow a_2=a_4, ~~ a_1 - a_2 = a_3,~~ a_1+a_2=2a_3+a_4$.
Now solve this for $a_1$ and $a_2$ (or $a_3$ and $a_4$) and we have $a_1=2a_3; ~~a_2=a_3$, replacing at $v$ equation get $$v = a_1(0,1,1)+a_2(1,-1,1) = 2a_3(0,1,1) + a_3(1,-1,1) = a_3(1,1,3) $$

Therefore, all $v$ that is in both spans is a linear combination of ${(1,1,3)}$. In other words, $span{(0,1,1),(1,−1,1)}∩span{(0,1,2),(1,0,1)}= span\{(1,1,3)\}$

Comment: If let's say I'm dealing with vectors in $R^5$, how can i then go about solving for $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, a_{4}, a{5}$? because it would be really complicated to find the one relation (e.g. $a_{1} = a_{5}$ and $a_{2}$ $=$ $3$ $a_{5}$).

Comment: you have to try solving the system of equations you'll get. It could exist more "free variables" and you get something like "$a_1= 5a_2 + 2a_4 ~~ a_3 = -5a_4 + a_2 - a_5$, there is no problem with that. But, it could be the case that the system just have the trivial solution (all variables are equal to zero) and it means that the intersection of the given span's is just {0}.

Comment: Note that the system of equations you'll get always have a solution: the trivial one. Because the vector $0$ belongs to any vector space (in particular belongs to every span of a set of vectors)

Comment: yups, many thanks! the system did turned out with just trivial solution.